# Disable Autoscroll in UI.router for specific links

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a ui.router view setup like this:

```
<div ui-view autoscroll></div>
```

I love the autoscroll most of the time, but sometimes need to disable it for specific links, is there a way to disable autoscroll or have it scroll to a different location for specific links.

Something like: `<a ui-sref="welcome" disableautoscroll>Welcome Page</a>`

Comment: have you found a solution ? I have  a list and each item opens a modal defined as a route. I dont want the list to scroll to top when opening uibmodal, but I can't get rid of this behaviour.